# Is there ServiceStack APIs available in F# language

Tags: c#, f#, servicestack

I am writing services using service stack in F# language. F# have types like 'option', 'tuple', etc., which is C# does not. Since service stack is implemented in C#, I am unable to manipulate these objects and not able to send these objects over the network.

I am thinking that if I get service stack in f#, so I may overcome this problem.

I searched on google none I get, if any has some information please provide.

Answer (score 3):

ServiceStack is only implemented in C#/.NET, you can still use [implement ServiceStack Services in F#](http://docs.servicestack.net/fsharp) but you'll need to stick to .NET CLR Types.

Comment: Thanks. If I implement service stack in f#, can I send option, tuple and discriminated union objects over the network?

Comment: @RavindraSinare You should avoid F# specific types in order to work in different serializers/formats.